# Are indexed tables faster than non indexed table while querying?

Tags: sql, database

Lets say we have to 2 identical tables with millions of rows and they have business transactions, both tables have the exact same information. One column specifies if the row is a "Sale" or "Order", other columns specify names(commonly repeated), date, amount, tax  etc....

Data in the tables are not organized so obviously Sales and Orders and other data are not sorted in any way.

The only diference is that one of the tables has an extra column that has its unique primary key.

If I queried the tables with the same queries with the same WHERE clauses that don't involve the primary key. Some query that involves maybe like : WHERE action = "sale" and name = "Bob Smith"

Will one of them be faster that the other for havix an index??

Comment: One table has a single index (primary key) and the other one has none at all?

Comment: Exactly. Only 1 index primary key in one one of the tables, the other are not indexed nor unique. And the queries i make don't involve the primary key at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every index is pure redundancy that:

- costs storage space,
- occupies cache space that could otherwise be occupied by something else
- must be maintained on INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE.

If the index can be utilized by a query, the speedup usually vastly outweighs the factors listed above. Conversely, if the index is not used, then it should not exist.

But before being tempted to eliminate the index and the key on top of it, keep in mind that **performance doesn't matter if data is incorrect**. A table without at least a primary key is wide open to duplicated rows due to application bugs<sup>1</sup>, cannot act as a parent endpoint of a FOREIGN KEY and its rows cannot be reasonably identified in client code.

Either try to identify a natural primary key that is already "embedded" in your data, or at least make a [surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) (as you did in one of the tables).

---

*<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, such table does not even represent a relation and this is no longer a "relational" database. The mathematical concept of relation is a set, not multiset, meaning an element is either in the set or isn't, but can't be in the set multiple times.*

Answer (score 1):

When you are querying with conditions on columns which don't have indexes on them, theoretically you should get pretty much the same performance regardless of presence/absence of PK. However, in practice it depends on RDMS implementation. From my experience I can tell for sure that in SQLServer you will see worse overall performance when querying heap tables (table with no clustered key), Oracle handles heaps much better and I'd expect the same performance.

Comment: What would make scanning heap tables worse than scanning b-trees? The rows are still searched in what is effectively random order. The heap, at least, might not be as fragmented. This is an honest question, not a nitpick.

Comment: @siride : As far as I understand, it requires less random reads from disk(surely, if clustered table is not very fragmented). Sequential reads are way cheaper even if size is the same compared to random. Disclaimer : it's my personal experience and my personal explanation (I may well be wrong, but I had the issues when adding clustered surrogate key to a table [ which by nature is heap - nothing unique and nothing has to be unique] makes a significant difference ). That happened in SQLServer 2008 R2, maybe it was some bug which doesn't exist in 2012; I haven't had a chance to check it.

Comment: but wouldn't it still read the data sequentially from the disk regardless of the table structure? The query would do an unorderded scan, so it could just read the table beginning to end, which could be done efficiently.

Comment: @siride : Yeah, but the problem (again, my opinion) is that rows in heap tables in SQLServers can be stored at any physical location and reading table from the beginning to the end may require more head moves back and forth . When it comes to index organized tables (or clustered, whatever terminology we want to use), the engine tries to store them more or less sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

The indexed table has an additional field that occupies space on disk.

Your description of the query can be satisfied in one of two ways.  Assume there are no indexes on the table for the columns in the `where` clause.  In that case, the query would be doing a full table scan.  The additional space for the primary key is then an issue.  Each record would be, say, 4 bytes longer in that record than in the other.  Typically, this would increase the number of tables that need to be read, and increase the time of the query.

You could guesstimate that if each base record is 100 bytes then each record with a primary key would be 104 bytes and the overall query would be about 4% longer (there are other factors at work, but this gives a high-level idea of what happens).

On the other hand, if indexes exist to satisfy the `where` clause *and* the result set is much, much smaller than the overall data, then the engine will look up values in the index, find the appropriate page and fetch the results from the page.  In this case, there would be about one page read per fetch, so the performance of the two should be similar.

All that said, I strongly support the notion that tables should have a unique auto-incremented primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is indexed on the fields you are using for the Where part of the query, an indexed table will be much faster.

The Mysql Reference explains it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Comment: That is the thing, of the table that has the primary key, that one is its only indexed column, the other columns are not indexed and are not unique in any way and there is no order in the insertion of data to the tables.